# not able to add new build to test flight

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, testflight, beta

I am facing a issue while add new build to external test itunes connect. 
Uploaded the build, while selecting new build build selectoin option is not available, see the screenshot below:

[image]

Some how managed build selection using inspect element, but next button is still disabled, tryed using inspect element too. See the screenshot below:

[image]

Faced the same issue once, but able to manage using inspect element.

Is it testflight bug?

Any one faced the issue, please comment below or answer it.

Edited-----------------
My user role is admin:
[image: User role Snapshot]

Comment: Provide a more detail about your user role in developer account

Comment: You can see my edited question for user role @Krunal

Comment: Do you have external users in list?

Comment: Yes I have 7 user in a group.

Comment: Try uploading new build, if that is still not solved. There may not be any other solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you've (your apple id) permission to invite external users in testfight.
Here is more details about user roles and permission for testflight: [User Roles - Manage TestFlight Testers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW24)

Also ensure, external users are there in '[External Users - Managing External Testers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html)' list.

Note: TestFlight takes 24 hrs to activate build for external users. Try after 24 hrs.

Snapshot shows your build 2 is already enabled for testing and
will expire after 89 days

[image]

Comment: My user role is Admin for all apps, please see my edited question, Build is enabled but next button is not enabled yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've experience similar kind of issue. Uploaded build is not available for Internal test group.

The issue is automatically resolved after 30-40min. Maybe apple took some time internally for some processing work.